# Rate of convergence of mean in a central limit theorem setting

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

I recently asked a question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168149/central-limit-theorem-and-convergence-of-means) that was the following:

> If $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,\ldots$ are i.i.d. with $P(Z_i=-1) = P(Z_i=+1) = \frac 12,$ then we have by the Central Limit Theorem that
>   $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i}{\sqrt{n}}\stackrel{d}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0,1),$
>   so that for any continuous bounded function $f,$ we have
>   $\mathbb{E}f\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\to\mathbb{E}f(W)$ where $W\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1).$
>   Now, $|\cdot|$ is not a bounded function, so it is not necessarily
>   true that
>
> $$\mathbb{E}\left|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i}{\sqrt{n}}\right|\to\mathbb{E}|W|.$$
>
> My question is whether the above is true for this specific
>   distribution of $Z_i.$ If not, what does
>   $\mathbb{E}\left|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i}{\sqrt{n}}\right|$ converge to
>   (if anything)?

I learnt from the answer given that uniform integrability guarantees the convergence $\mathbb{E}\left|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i}{\sqrt{n}}\right|\to\mathbb{E}|W|.$ However, I am interested in knowing the rate of convergence for this particular example. Can you help me with some bound on how fast the sequence converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $Y_n:=n^{-1/2}|\sum_{j=1}^nZ_j|$.

From the Berry-Esseen theorem, we have for some universal constant $C$, 
$$\tag{1}|\mu\{Y_n>t\}-\mu\{|W|>t\}|\leqslant \frac C{\sqrt n}.$$
For any positive $R$, 
$\mathbb E[Y_n\chi_{\{Y_n>R\}}|\leqslant R^{-1}$ and a similar inequality holds for $|W|$. Using (1) and the formula $\mathbb E[X]=\int_0^{+\infty}\mu\{X>t\}\mathrm dt$ valid for a non-negative random variable $X$, we obtain 
$$\tag{2}|\mathbb E[Y_n]-\mathbb E|Z||\leqslant C\left(\frac{R}{\sqrt n}+\frac 1R\right).$$
Optimizing the RHS of (2) in $R$, we obtain that for some constant $C$ independent of $n$, 
$$|\mathbb E[Y_n]-\mathbb E|Z||\leqslant \frac{C}{n^{1/4}}.$$