# Bounding the moments of sample-mean of i.i.d. zero-mean r.v.

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, expected-value, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be given, and they are i.i.d. r.v.'s.
(For simplicity let $X_i$ take real values, but complex case seems easy to generalize.)
Suppose $\mathbb{E}(X_i) =0$ and w.l.o.g. let $\mathbb{E}(|X_i|^2) =1$.
Assume, moreover, $\mathbb{E}(|X_i|^k) <\infty$ for $k=3,4,5...$.

Denote
$$Y_N :=N^{-1/2} (X_1 + \dotsc + X_N)$$

Let $\chi$ be standard Normal.
It would seem to us that, from central limit theorem, there distribution are approximately equal:

$$F_{Y_N} \approx F_\chi$$

Thus, **is there a bound**

$$\mathbb{E} (|Y_N|^k) \leq \eta(N) \mathbb{E} (|\chi|^k)?$$

where $\eta$ is not related to the distribution of $X$, but universal, and

$$0 \leq \limsup_{N \to \infty} \eta (N) \leq M <\infty?$$

What I have looked up, not sure if these helps:

- [Marcinkiewicz–Zygmund inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcinkiewicz%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality) (How can we bound the constants $B_p$?)
- In Durrett *Probability* p.71, there is a related theorem (labeled 2.5.7): for any $\epsilon >0$, a.s.,

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac {Y_N} {(\log N)^{1/2+\epsilon}} = 0$$

Comment: How can $\eta(N) \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$? It seems like this is not true even if each $X_i$ is drawn from a standard Normal distribution. See [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177700055) for some bounds.

Comment: Additionally, you might be interested in [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072920/convergence-of-third-moment-in-central-limit-theorem). If you want bounds on the cdf under milder assumptions, you can look at the [Berry-Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem). Also, the statement you quoted from Durrett seems to be similar to [the law of the iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm).

Comment: Ah ... I see. I probably want $\eta(N) < M < \infty$. Have edited.